# How not to multiply real time and bake shadows? (Unity)

Tags: unity, rendering, shadows, shadow-mapping, lightmap

I have one Light Source ( Directional Light ) with Mixed Mode.
Lighting Mode in Lighting Window I seted to Subtractive.

What the problem looks like
[image]

How I would like the shadows to blend. How to achieve this effect?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer - Change RealTime Shadow Color in Environment Tab in Lignting Window so that the color matches the baked shadow color